# Loading a html page inside a div with it's jQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, load

I want to load a page with Image Slider, inside a div using .Load() method.
It's working but Slider jQuery script within the html page doesn't work and it's css too.

how can I fix this?

Comment: Any error logs in your browser debugger?

Comment: you need to share the code otherwise we will be not knowing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it is difficult to tell what is going on or even what you're looking to do. From your explanation, here is the jquery for a page I'm currently working on:

```
$('input[type="image"].thumbnail').click(function() {
    var pageName = this.id;
    $('#lookBookWindow').load(pageName + '.html', function() {
        $('#lookbookSlider').cycle( {
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        timeout: 0,
        pause: false,
        next: '#next',
        prev: '#prev',
        });
    });
}).first().click();
```

".thumbnail", "#lookBookWindow" and "#lookbookSlider" are specific to my project. Hopefully this structure will help figure out your problem.